# Alert on HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

In jquery one can do an event like this:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Is it possible to do this when a page is doing a HTTP request to a certain URL? Maybe with plain Javascript? 
It shouldent matter what kind of request (ea AJAX or post or whatever)

```
$( "#target" ).???ON_HTTP_REQUEST???(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

I Googled a LOT but there is nothing on this.

Comment: What do you call here <<ON_HTTP_REQUEST>>? An ajax request or what?

Comment: @roasted Its not about 'calling' but 'listening' to when a page is loading external data, and then do something like alert the URL of the HTTP request

Comment: I understood it, i mean WHAT do you call http request? Apparently not only ajax request following your comment in adeneo's answer. Then for me, your question doesn't make sense. Could you provide a more complete example of what you are looking for?

Comment: @roasted Are all HTTP requests AJAX request? (I really dont know)

Comment: Of course not, that's why i was asking what you are looking for... Apparently you want to spoof URL and make your users believe they are redirected somewhere else, is it?

Comment: @roasted I just want to get as much information as possible. I need to know the URL of the secondary data to (for example) handle some Javascript on the page. Its part of a bigger project, it doesnt really concern my end users

Comment: anchor tag `<a>` would do a request to by loading the page targeted by href attribute, you have to take care of it too

Comment: @roasted I dont understand....What I mean is that when scraping a website one can not handle dynamic content generated by javascript, because a secondary HTTP request is made and you will face cross-domain restriction. However (in theory) you could 'capture' the HTTP request and then redirect to your own 'scraper' which will scrape THAT URL and return the data. This way you can have some basic support for dynamic content. If you know anything that could help me achieve this please let me know. The answer provided is good but I still have to get the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably [$.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), which fires whenever an ajax call starts up (POST and GET):

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    alert("Ajax started");
});
```

from the docs:

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether
>   there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in
>   progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers
>   that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at
>   this time.

Comment: I'd think about load() method instead

Comment: Do you think there is an universal code which does this also on POST and other types of requests? Because not every HTTP request is AJAX

Comment: @user1532999 - Ajax is Asyncronous Javascript And XML, it does both POST and GET requests. If you're doing requests without ajax, the page reloads, and you won't need an event.

Comment: @user1532999 a request wich is not ajax would make your entire document obsolete, meaning you have to call click handler on the new loaded document

Comment: Do you guys think its possible to spoof the URl of the request? Im scraping a page and I would like to get the URL and do stuff with it

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function( event, jqxhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/test.html" ) {
    alert( "loading ajax/test.html" );
  }
});
```